# Interpolate Matplotlib ListedColormap

Tags: matplotlib

I have the following plot which uses a custom `color_map` using `ListedColormap`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np
from cmath import phase

s = 10
row, col = np.indices((s * 2, s * 2))
z = (col - s) + (row - s) * 1j

color_map = ListedColormap([[5, 175, 242],[132, 191, 4],[242, 159, 5],[242, 62, 22],[175, 114, 211]])

ax1 = plot.subplot()
space = [-s,s,-s,s]
ax1.imshow(np.vectorize(phase)(z), extent=space, cmap=color_map)
```

I currently have 5 custom colours so it shows

[image]

Is there a way to interpolate these colours. So when plotting rather than the pixel using its closest key, it instead linear interpolates between the two values in the window?

If not possible with the matplotlib library, maybe there is a way to pass `ListedColormap` a set of already interpolated colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a `LinearSegmentedColormap` and normalize your color values by 255:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np
from cmath import phase

s = 10
row, col = np.indices((s * 2, s * 2))
z = (col - s) + (row - s) * 1j

colors = np.array([
    [5,   175, 242],
    [132, 191, 4  ], 
    [242, 159, 5  ],
    [242, 62,  22 ],
    [175, 114, 211]]
) / 255

color_map = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

ax1 = plot.subplot()
space = [-s,s,-s,s]
ax1.imshow(np.vectorize(phase)(z), extent=space, cmap=color_map)

plot.show()
```

[image]